# Error while configuring UCP replica

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry, ucp, docker-ucp

I have installed UCP master on a node and able to login using `admin/orca`

The UCP admin fingerprint is as below

```
23:B9:9E:08:B5:67:73:0A:C7:17:07:76:56:B2:F3:D2:73:CE:B5:74
```

Now, I am trying to configure UCP replica on a separate node using the following command

```
docker run --rm -i --env UCP_ADMIN_USER=admin --env UCP_ADMIN_PASSWORD=orca -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name ucp docker/ucp join --replica --url https://10.211.144.177 --san r1.ucp.abc.com --fingerprint 23:B9:9E:08:B5:67:73:0A:C7:17:07:76:56:B2:F3:D2:73:CE:B5:74
```

After I run the above command, I am getting the following error:

```
ERRO[0102] Orca didn't come up within 1m0s.  Run "docker logs ucp-controller" for more details
FATA[0102] Unable to connect to system
```

Please help me resolve the error

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/ucp/evaluation-install/ Did you did Step 6. License your installation?

Comment: Yes i successfully uploaded the license on the UCP master before starting configuring UCP replica

Comment: Step 7? $ docker run --rm -it \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
--name ucp docker/ucp join -i \
--host-address $(docker-machine ip node2)

Comment: I provided the host-address but still getting the same error.  
` DEBU[0030] Starting swarm manager
DEBU[0031] Swarm manager started on x.x.x.x:2376
DEBU[0031] Checking for liveness of https://x.x.x.x:2376
DEBU[0032] Connected to https://x.x.x.x:2376 b585df9261b0
DEBU[0032] Trusting certs with subjects: [010UUCP Cluster Root CA]
DEBU[0032] Starting UCP controller
DEBU[0034] Checking for liveness of https://x.x.x.x:443/_ping
ERRO[0094] Orca didn't come up within 1m0s.  Run "docker logs ucp-controller" for more details
FATA[0094] Unable to connect to system `

Comment: docker logs ucp-controller ?

Comment: {"level":"info","msg":"Swarm CA not responding - Post https://x.x.x.x:12381/api/v1/cfssl/info: dial tcp x.x.x.x:12381: getsockopt: connection refused","time":"2016-04-27T19:09:36Z"}

Comment: the error says that Swarm CA not responding

Comment: https://github.com/docker/swarm/issues/311 https://github.com/docker/swarm/issues/781 Closing this one, let us know if you still have this issue with swarm 1.0.0. There was known issues on RHEL and fedora but this is likely fixed by now. Also please update to a recent and supported docker version (1.8 or 1.9).

Comment: I went to the link but want to know what should i do to get rid of this error. what docker command should i run??

Comment: I am using docker Version: 1.10.3